# CSS Tooltip Overlap Issue

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I'm working with a simple CSS and HTML tooltip. The general gist of the layout is there are a number of images in a row, with several rows of these images. Each image has some text and a tooltip. When the mouse rolls over the image a tooltip appears. The problem is when the tooltip list appears the mouse-over does not extend to the bottom of the tooltip list. If the current open list overlaps the image in the next row below, the current tooltip will disappear as you roll your mouse down through it.

Here's a JSFiddle of what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/kxskzrsr/

If you roll over the first image a tooltip list will appear. If you try to scroll to the bottom of the tooltip list it will cut out and open the tooltip for the image below instead of staying open in the current tooltip.

```css
.centre-profiles {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px; 
}

.team-pic { 
    position:relative;
    background-color:#99C; 
}

.team-name {
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:60%;
    padding-top:90px;
}

.bg-image-sm {
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:210px;
    max-height:150px;
    padding-right:15px;
}

.transparent-maroon  {
    position:absolute;
    color:#fff;
    background: rgba(119, 0, 0, 0.8);
    width:210px;
    text-align:center;
    height:40px;
    z-index:20;
    top:110px;
}


/* Tooltip text */

.bg-image-sm .tooltiptext-sm {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 210px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    color: #000;
    font-size:50%;
    line-height:20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    opacity: 0;

/* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -105px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    z-index: 1;
}


/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */

.bg-image-sm:hover .tooltiptext-sm {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="centre-profiles">

  <div class="bg-image-sm">
    <div class="team-pic">
      <img src="images/bg1.jpg" width="210" height="150">
      <div class="transparent-maroon">
        <span class="team-name">Name</span><br>
        <span class="tooltiptext-sm">Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text Last<br />
Tooltip text<br /></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bg-image-sm">
    <div class="team-pic">
      <img src="images/bg1.jpg" width="210" height="150">
      <div class="transparent-maroon">
        <span class="team-name">Name</span><br>
        <span class="tooltiptext-sm">Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br /></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bg-image-sm">
    <div class="team-pic">
      <img src="images/bg1.jpg" width="210" height="150">
      <div class="transparent-maroon">
        <span class="team-name">Name</span><br>
        <span class="tooltiptext-sm">Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br /></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bg-image-sm">
    <div class="team-pic">
      <img src="images/bg1.jpg" width="210" height="150">
      <div class="transparent-maroon">
        <span class="team-name">Name</span><br>
        <span class="tooltiptext-sm">Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br /></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bg-image-sm">
    <div class="team-pic">
      <img src="images/bg1.jpg" width="210" height="150">
      <div class="transparent-maroon">
        <span class="team-name">Name</span><br>
        <span class="tooltiptext-sm">Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br /></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bg-image-sm">
    <div class="team-pic">
      <img src="images/bg1.jpg" width="210" height="150">
      <div class="transparent-maroon">
        <span class="team-name">Name</span><br>
        <span class="tooltiptext-sm">Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text Last<br />Tooltip text<br />
</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work now, remove all z-indexing from your css, with the exception of `.bg-image-sm .tooltiptext-sm`

https://jsfiddle.net/kxskzrsr/3/

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


.team-row {
 
}

.team-member {
 display:inline-block;
 max-width:210px;
 max-height:150px;
 
}

.team-pic {
 position:relative;
 background-color:#99C;
 
}

.transparent-red  {
 position:absolute;
 color:#fff;
 background: rgba(142, 0, 0, 0.8);
 width:210px;
 text-align:center;
 height:40px;
 /* z-index:20; */
 top:110px;
}

.team-name {
 line-height:40px;
 font-size:60%;
 padding-top:90px;
 
}

.team-title {
 line-height: 1px;
 font-size:40%;
 
}


/* Tooltip text */
.team-member .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 210px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    color: #000;
 font-size:50%;
 line-height:20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
 
    /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: absolute;
    /* z-index: 1; */
 top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -105px;
 
 opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
 
}




/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.team-member:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
}


.centre-profiles {

 margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px; 
 
}


/********  Code for smaller image with red overlay 210 x 150 ********/

.bg-image-sm {
 display:inline-block;
 max-width:210px;
 max-height:150px;
 padding-right:15px;
}


.transparent-maroon  {
 position:absolute;
 color:#fff;
 background: rgba(119, 0, 0, 0.8);
 width:210px;
 text-align:center;
 height:40px;
 /* z-index:20; */
 top:110px;
}


/* Tooltip text */
.bg-image-sm .tooltiptext-sm {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 210px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    color: #000;
 font-size:50%;
 line-height:20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
 
 opacity: 0;
 
/* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -105px;
 opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
 z-index: 100 !important;
 
}


/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.bg-image-sm:hover .tooltiptext-sm {
    visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="centre-profiles">

<div class="bg-image-sm"><div class="team-pic">
<img src="images/bg1.jpg" width="210" height="150">
<div class="transparent-maroon">
<span class="team-name">Name</span><br>
<span class="tooltiptext-sm">Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text Last<br />
Tooltip text<br /></span>
</div></div></div>

<div class="bg-image-sm"><div class="team-pic">
<img src="images/bg1.jpg" width="210" height="150">
<div class="transparent-maroon">
<span class="team-name">Name</span><br>
<span class="tooltiptext-sm">Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br /></span>
</div></div></div>

<div class="bg-image-sm"><div class="team-pic">
<img src="images/bg1.jpg" width="210" height="150">
<div class="transparent-maroon">
<span class="team-name">Name</span><br>
<span class="tooltiptext-sm">Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br /></span>
</div></div></div>

<div class="bg-image-sm"><div class="team-pic">
<img src="images/bg1.jpg" width="210" height="150">
<div class="transparent-maroon">
<span class="team-name">Name</span><br>
<span class="tooltiptext-sm">Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br /></span>
</div></div></div>

<div class="bg-image-sm"><div class="team-pic">
<img src="images/bg1.jpg" width="210" height="150">
<div class="transparent-maroon">
<span class="team-name">Name</span><br>
<span class="tooltiptext-sm">Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br /></span>
</div></div></div>

<div class="bg-image-sm"><div class="team-pic">
<img src="images/bg1.jpg" width="210" height="150">
<div class="transparent-maroon">
<span class="team-name">Name</span><br>
<span class="tooltiptext-sm">Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text Last<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text<br />
Tooltip text<br />Tooltip text Last<br /></span>
</div></div></div>


</div>
```